# Angular what is the best method generating big reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

For example I have a page with 35 `inputs` and 1 save `button`, also I can add more `input` fields by clicking on a `button`, so probably 35+ `input` fields. The problem is that it is hard to handle all `form` and its logic in one page in the other hand it is harder to divide it in to `components` (For example divide it in 4-5 `components`).

1. Render all form and it's logic to one `component`
2. Divide form to `components` - but I think this will make a big mess because I don't have a button to save in each component so this will lead to a bigger mess ,so there should be a lot of `EventEmitters`, `Input`, `Outputs`.

**Maybe You know a better way to handle angular reactive forms ? I will accept any information that will help me ease my code.** Examples would be fine

Error :

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

   Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future Web, I imagine an aproach can be divided your form in formGroup,e.g.

```
form=new FormGroup({
   personalData:new FormGroup({
        ...
   }),
   address:new FormGroup({
        ...
   })
   jobs:new FormArray([...])
})
```

And create different components app-form-personal-data, app-form-adress, app-form-jobs

Your main.app become like

```
<app-form-personal-data [formGroup]="form.get('personalData')"></app-form-personal-data>
<app-form-address [formGroup]="form.get('address')"></app-form-address>
<app-form-jobs [formGroup]="form.get('jobs')"></app-form-jobs>
<button (click)="submit(form)">
```

Or use a [material stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) where becomes like

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="form.get('personalData')">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Personal data</ng-template>
      <app-form-personal-data [formGroup]="form.get('personalData')"></app-form-personal-data>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="form.get('address')">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Adress</ng-template>
      <app-form-address [formGroup]="form.get('address')"></app-form-address>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="form.get('jobs')">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Adress</ng-template>
      <app-form-jobs [formGroup]="form.get('jobs')"></app-form-jobs>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    <pre>{{form?.value|json}}</pre>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

(I left in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzrev4?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html) a little example with material-stepper)

your forms components becomes like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form1',
  template:`
  <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css'],
})
export class Form1 {
  @Input()formGroup:FormGroup
}
```

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer, I will use this method ! There is one problem, when I use [formGroup] as an input, I get an error, check my edited question.

Comment: take accout that in the forms components [formGroup] is a `@Input()` -I choose this name, but can be another-. Sometimes is usefull use the construction <div *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup"..> to avoid initial errors

Answer (score 0):

you can check [ng-dynamic-forms](https://www.google.com/search?q=ng-dynamic%20form&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIL862IL862&oq=ng-dynamic%20form&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.4240j0j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

NG Dynamic Forms is a rapid form development library based on the official Angular dynamic forms guide.

It fully automates form UI creation by introducing a set of maintainable form control models and dynamic form control components

Out of the box support is provided for all popular UI libraries including Bootstrap, Foundation, Ionic, Kendo, Material, NG Bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap and PrimeNG.

Explore it live in action!

Comment: I think its great, but there is one problem, I use custom components for buttons,selects, datepicks, inputs and etc... So I can't use this in my case.

Comment: you can change the design of each input of course, there is an option to use basic-ui which is plain html.

Answer (score 0):

You will not need eventemitters, inputs and outputs. You simply add to your root form using ControlValueAccessors. Have a read here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Also, when dynamically adding fields, please have a look at the FormControlArray, which you can find in the docs. Make sure to check out this page:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Answer (score 0):

There a good way to do it,
Let assume that you have screens (forms)
Let all your screens extend from an abstract class which will have a property of type formArray , let's call it : array !
For each of your custom components , add three essential properties :
-An ID (bind it to the html component id) for uniqueness,
-That array (property of the screen) as an input,
-And a formGroup specific to your custom component.
 and in the creation of your components (e.g ngOnInit) ,
Do some code like this (for each component add his inner formGroup to the parent array)

```
 this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  [this.id]: new FormControl(null, {
    validators: (if any)
  })
});
```

That's it. By this way you can handle everything of your form (validation , values ...).